# Display dataframe index name with Streamlit

Tags: pandas, streamlit

The following code does not display the name of the index:

```
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st

df = pd.DataFrame(['row1', 'row2'], index=pd.Index([1, 2], name='my_index'))
st.write(df)
```

[image: Dataframe without]

Is there a way to have `my_index` displayed like you would do in a jupyter notebook?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [streamlit doc](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/write-magic/st.write) it will write dataframe as a table. So the index name is not shown.

To show the `my_index` name, reset the index to default and as a result the `my_index` will become a normal column. Add the following before st.write().

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

##### Output

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution using pandas dataframe `to_html()` method:

```
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st

df = pd.DataFrame(['row1', 'row2'], index=pd.Index([1, 2], name='my_index'))
st.write(df.to_html(), unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

This results with the following output:

[image: Output1]

If you want the index and columns names to be in the same header row you can use the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st

df = pd.DataFrame(['row1', 'row2'], index=pd.Index([1, 2], name='my_index'))
df.columns.name = df.index.name
df.index.name = None
st.write(df.to_html(), unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

This results with the following output:

[image: Output2]

**Note** - if you have a large dataset and want to limit the number of rows use `df.to_html(max_rows=N)` instead where N is the number of rows you want to dispplay.

Comment: For large dataframes the "to_html()" solution displays the whole thing while st.write(df) displays a scrollable table.